# Why is tsc checking for node_modules from parent directory in spite of the fact that I issue tsc from within subfolder?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

Maybe a dumb question, but I am stuck with the following:

I have a project with following structure:

```
 - package.json
 - tsconfig.json
 - node_modules
 - lib
   - folder1
   - folder2
   ...
 - subproject
   - package.json
   - tsconfig.json
```

The thing is that when I am running npm install and run tsc when the subproject on its own (without beging in the subfolder but totally seperate project) everything is fine, compilation succeeds.

But when I enter subproject/ folder and the structure is as above, I am getting compilation errors when on the root folder there is already node_modules folder. Why does typescript event checks the root node_modules folder? (root folder tsconfig.json has subproject in excludes). I am issueing compilation from within subproject/ folder. But obviously there are some typing conflicts when root node_modules folder is present, i.e.:

```
../../node_modules/@types/superagent/index.d.ts:23:10 - error TS2305: Module '"buffer"' has no exported member 'Blob'
```

Shouldn't tsconfig when run from inside subproject folder consider this subproject folder as root? What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` for the subproject?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko yes I did

Comment: Nesting projects like that is undesirable because Node walks up the directory tree trying to resolve dependencies. TypeScript tries to emulate this behavior in its type checking and module resolution behavior. You can prevent the specific error by setting `"typeRoots"`. But there are runtime issues to consider such as implicit dependencies